# How to creat a NSString using copied code snippets from my own app which are then viewed in a TextView control in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I a a bit new, but did do a Google search and here on Stack, but with no results that helped me solve this issue.  I have taken some Objective-C via Lynda.com courses with Simon Allardice, which were great starting points, but what I need to do is this:

I am writing a simple demo / reference app that has a bunch of controls on the interface (UIButton, UISwitch etc).  I also have to the right, a TextView control.  When the user touches the button for example, I want to show the code I used to perform the actions in the method as sort of a "how to" or "How I did that" reference for myself.

I have tried:

NSString *myCode = @"copied code snipped into here";

But I get a warning that is not clear to me.  I thought that perhaps I needed to use the 'stringWithFormat' method on the NSString, but that did not work out either.  So, how can I copy snippets of code into a NSString var so that I can reference it i my app at runtime showing the text in the TextView control?

Thanks

Comment: If i have well understood, you need to how to set a placeholder to your UITextView ?

Comment: I don't know of anything which can convert code into string. You'd have to hardcode that.

Comment: "But I get a warning that is not clear to me." *What* warning? "I thought that perhaps I needed to use... but that did not work out either." *How do you know* it didn't work out? What did you expect to happen, and what happened instead? Simply saying "It doesn't work" doesn't assist anyone in helping you.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing special about code. It's just text, and you can easily put it into a string. The only thing you need to watch out for is special characters like quotation marks and line endings. You'll need to escape the quotes with a backslash so that the quotes are interpreted as part of the string rather than the end of the string. Similarly, use an appropriate escape sequence for your line endings.

So, if your code looks like this:

```
if (self.label) {
    self.label.text = @"Hello, world!";
}
```

you should do something like this:

```
NSString *codeString = @"if (self.label) {\nself.label.text = @\"Hello, world!\";\n}"
```

Comment: I have tried your suggested approach Caleb, but get no positive results.  I have placed a '\' before each double-quote, where they are in the lines of source code, and '\n'

Comment: I tried to place escape chars '\' before any double-quote chars and also put '\n' at the end / after characters where a crlf would normally be, but it still is not working.  What if I saved code to a text file, added it to my project and referred to it some how?  Also, how do I do that?  I think it would be easier and less tetius.

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Comments on your question asked for the error/warning message you're getting, but you haven't supplied it. It's hard to really help in that case.

Comment: I get a warning that states that I am missing a Terminating Char, but I , as far as I can see, have put the escape after each "{", "}" and double-quote in the code snippet I am using to construct the NSString from.  I was thinking to add a RTF or TXT file and read it in to a var.  Is this an option, and if so, how do I do that?

Comment: There's no reason to escape curly brackets, and in any case the escape character (`\`) goes *before* the character you're trying to escape, not after. **Edit your question to include the *actual message* and a piece of *actual code* that causes the message.** There's no reason that you'd need to load the code from a separate file just to solve this problem, although it's certainly possible to create a string from a file if that makes sense for your application. The NSString documentation is pretty clear on how to do that.

Comment: Caleb,  Here is the NSString I am trying to create from the code in my 'viewDidLoad' method.  It generates one error and one warning

Error:  Unexpected "@" in program
Warning:  Missing terminating "" character

I have to paste the actual code in the next comment, so look there as it was too large to add in this message along with my explanation here.  As you will see, I placed escape chars BEFORE all (") in the code and a newline (\n) at the end of lines.  What am I missing or doing wrong?  See code in next comment.

Comment: Here is the code for the NSString I spoke of above:

NSString *viewDidLoadCode =@"- (void)viewDidLoad\n
{\n
    [super viewDidLoad];\n
    
    UIAlertView *myAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert Title" message:@"The text of your alert message goes here.\n" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];\n\n
    
    [myAlert show];\n
    
    if (filePath) {\n
        NSString *myText = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath];\n
        if (myText) {
            self.txtCode.text= myText;\n
        }\n
    }\n
    
}\"\n";

Comment: Caleb,  Here is the actual (unedited for NSString) code from my 'viewDidLoad' method I was trying to use to create the NSString from. To Compare.

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIAlertView *myAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert Title" message:@"The text of your alert message goes here.\n" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    
    [myAlert show];
    
    if (filePath) {
        NSString *myText = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
        if (myText) {
            self.txtCode.text= myText;
        }
    }

}